# Create a function to add a black border around an image

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am taking a class and we are supposed to make a function that adds a border to an image. I first made a program(commented out at the bottom of this code) that creates a border of ten pixels around the image, which worked as I expected. I transferred the code to the function and now it has a bug. I replaced 10 with the parameter(borderWidth) from the function addBorder, and for some reason the function only places the border on the top and left side of the image, rather than all the way around. I assume the bug is in the if statements, but I cannot find it, nor do I understand why it works as a program, but not as a function.

```
//create a function to change a single pixel to black
function setBlack(pixel){
    pixel.setRed(0);
    pixel.setGreen(0);
    pixel.setBlue(0);
    return false;
}
//create a function to add a black border around an image 

function addBorder(pixel, image, borderWidth){
    var x = pixel.getX();
    var y = pixel.getY();
    if(x <= img.getWidth() + borderWidth - img.getWidth() || x >= img.getWidth - borderWidth){
        return pixel;
    }
    if(y <= img.getHeight() + borderWidth - img.getHeight() || y >= img.getHeight - borderWidth){
        return pixel;
    }
    return false;
}

var img = new SimpleImage("palm-and-beach.png");
img.setSize(200, 200);

for(pixel of img.values()){
    if(addBorder(pixel, img, 10)){
        setBlack(pixel);
    }
}
print(img);
```

Comment: Where is `SimpleImage` defined?

Comment: Torazaburo, SimpleImage is defined in the 'Duke learn to program' library. They also utilize their own editing environment for the javascript portion of the class. We are able to write code in one box, run it, and it's interpreted to output in another box. For the html/css portion of the class we use codepen, which is a live editor, if you haven't heard of it. They're quite useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to put () after the function referance `img.getWidth()`

```
function addBorder(pixel, image, borderWidth){
    //                     ^^
    // should be referencing image        
    var x = pixel.getX();
    var y = pixel.getY();
    if(x <= img.getWidth() + borderWidth - img.getWidth() || x >= img.getWidth  - borderWidth){
    //                                                                    ^^ 
    //                                                            This is a function call missing ()
        return pixel;
    }
    if(y <= img.getHeight() + borderWidth - img.getHeight() || y >= img.getHeight - borderWidth){
    //                                                                          ^^ 
    //                                                            This is a function call missing ()

        return pixel;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Also `img.getWidth() + borderWidth - img.getWidth()` is redundant `borderWidth` is all you need same with height. Also should be returning `true` not `pixel` when over border pixels.

Correcting the function.

```
function addBorder(pixel, image, borderWidth){
    var x = pixel.getX();
    var y = pixel.getY();
    var w = image.getWidth();
    var h = image.getHeight();
    if(x <= borderWidth || x >= w  - borderWidth){
        return true;
    }
    if(y <= borderWidth || y >= h - borderWidth){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

You are doing an exercise but to let you know there is a much quicker (CPU time) way to add a border

```
function addBorder(image, borderStyle, borderWidth){
     // create new image
     var bImage = document.createElement("canvas");
     // set size to include border
     bImage.width = image.width + borderWidth * 2;
     bImage.height = image.height + borderWidth * 2;
     var ctx = bImage.getContext("2d");
     ctx.fillStyle = borderStyle;
     // fill it with border colour
     ctx.fillRect(0, 0, bImage.width, bImage.height);
     // draw the image 
     ctx.drawImage(image, borderWidth, borderWidth);
     return bImage; // done
 }
```

Comment: Blindman67, yes, thank you! I kept going over each line and I just couldn't see it. Also, sorry the commented out portion - the program I wrote before hand - was eliminated. I put it in there, but somewhere between me entering the question and it being published, it was removed. I did try your suggestion on the redundancy, but it returned an entirely black photo. Thank you for taking the time to look over it!

Comment: @Nibble0xA I just noticed another problem, you `return pixel` when at border pixels, you should be returning `false` (I will update the answer). I don't know why the image is black as the logic is sound but I am unfamiliar with the library so can only guess. BTW there is a way easier way of adding a boarder to an image. Ill add it to the update

Comment: I had posted this below, but I didn't write your name correctly. I agree that the function closes the image reference. When I made the function and program I was curious and tried both and both were interpreted without error. I understood as you say, closed by the function and then, I assume, pointed to when the addBorder is called using the img variable. Right? Or, img is placed in the image box (address in memory), if you're thinking a lower level of abstraction... Am I understanding the semantics correctly?

Comment: @Nibble0xA In this case you can think of it as img was still in scope within the function. Javascript closure is hard to explain in a few words, its more than just being in scope, the variables closed over get new copies  to the references they hold and that have a life the length of the functions context. Best look it up rather than try to understand what I am ineffectively trying to say.

Comment: I had wondered about using a fgimg and a bgimg. Part of our class is working on "the green screen problem", where we use both of those and another output image. I'm curious, I see your reasoning for the return, but I want to understand further. Is it return false; because an if statement is only passed over once thus having to terminate for each iteration when called by the for loop?

Comment: @Nibble0xA the loop will continue until all the pixels have been process (I am guessing as I don't use the library). For each pixel you ask the function  `addBorder` (a better name would `isBorder`) if the pixel is a border pixel or not. If the function returns true then you change the value of the pixel to black. To follow the code read it in order following the code flow. `If(something === true){return true}; ` it will exit the function with the value true, if not then keep going down the function until there is a return or no more statements.

Comment: Oh yeah! I recall that being discussed, briefly, in one of the earlier lessons. I will ask one of the teachers to elaborate, cause I'd really like to understand it further. Thank you again for taking time to help me, and thank you for the extra option. I think I can see how it's supposed to work, but there are definitely concepts that have not been covered. It's interesting you use document.createElement() to make a new image. Must be the library we are using that is different. For the class it is - var bgimg = new SimpleImage ("your-img.filetype");

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your code, it appears you are passing "img" to addBorder:

```
if(addBorder(pixel, img, 10)){
        setBlack(pixel);
    }
```

But the parameter in your function is "image" and you are modifying img in the function:

```
function addBorder(pixel, image, borderWidth){
    ...
    if(x <= img.getWidth() + borderWidth - img.getWidth())
    ...
    }
```

I think it should be `if(x <= image.getWidth() + borderWidth - image.getWidth())`

Comment: Even though there is an inconsistent referance the object referance `img` is closed over by the function `addBoarder`. Changing the reference to identifier to `image` in this case has no effect.

Comment: Blindman67, I agree that the function closes the image reference. When I made the function and program I was curious and tried both and both were interpreted without error. I understood as you say, closed by the function and then pointed to when the addBorder is called using the img variable. Right? Or, img is placed in the image box (address in memory)? If you're thinking a lower level of abstraction...yes?